# inoremap <C-S> <esc>:w<CR> i

Tags: vimrc

I have the following command in my `vimrc`file:

```
inoremap <C-S> <esc>:w<CR> i
```

which saves the file in insert mode but, for some reason, it also adds an extra space where cursor is present.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally added a whitespace at the end of the mapping.

Comment: @JairLópez is right: the line you copy pasted in your question contains the extra trailing whitespace. Make sure that you remove it and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `<c-o>` to execute your command.

```
inoremap <c-s> <c-o>:w<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `:startinsert<CR>` instead of `i`.